# access variables from Appliction.cfc

Tags: database, coldfusion, cfquery, coldfusion-10, application.cfc

I would like to know the new way of calling variables from the Application.cfc file when using the script function, which has the format of "this.something" My example:

```
component {

    // application variables
    this.datasource = "my DSN";

}
```

Now in my cfquery I want to access this. I used in the past I would use [cfset REQUEST.dataSource ="MyDSN"] in the Application.cfc, and then in my cfqrey I would say;

```
<cfquery name="rs_dailytip" datasource="#REQUEST.dataSource#">
My SQL
</cfquery>
```

My question is how to do this with the new Application.cfc where I am using "this.datasource"?

Comment: You should specify which version of ColdFusion you are using.

Comment: I am using ColdFusion 10, sorry about not saying that.

Answer (score 8):

To answer this specific question, you do NOT need to provide the datasource attribute.  Your query should look like this:

```
<cfquery name='Q'>
    SQL GOES HERE
</cfquery>
```

THIS.datasource becomes the default datasource (as of CF9).

Comment: Hi Evik, thanks so much! I just tested this, and orks like you say, I can't thank you enough ;)

Comment: If the answer was correct, but sure to select it as the correct answer. I am glad I could help you.

Answer (score 2):

@EvikJames is correct about the datasource attribute, but I believe if you want access to use other variables like APPLICATION.SUPPORT_EMAIL I would use the APPLICATION scope. Others may disagree, but that's what I do and it works fine.

Comment: Yes, you can use `application.variableName` but it would introduce coupling within the component. The best way would be add a method argument and pass it in that way.

Comment: @AlexP, I'm not a CS major so I apologize for my ignorance, but could you please explain "coupling within the component" and give an example of a method argument?

Comment: I don't want to digress too far from the original question but take a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming) and method arguments is simply passing the `application.variableName` **to** the function rather than calling it **within**. http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=UDFs_08.html